can't connect to internet after 24.04 studio installation
i ran ubuntustudio 24.04 from a live thumb drive without problems
and liked the way it worked.  i had previously installed 24.04 desktop
and that worked fine as well.  both distributions connected to the
internet without problems.  but the studio installation can't connect
to the internet although both the live studio and the installed desktop
connect seamlessly and automatically.  i've installed the studio on
an ssd in a dual boot configuration with windows 10; that connects to
the internet as well.  when i disconnect the ethernet cable from my
desktop the studio shows that it's disconnected and when i connect it
that warning goes away.  i'm not sure what diagnostics i should run
to find the problem.  thanks for any suggestions--sid
